# Get permission to live in italy

Tags: resident-permit, marriage, italy, eu-spouses

I am living in Italy now but I don't have any document or permission to stay here (I am non-EU citizen). 
If I married an Italian woman here in Italy can I get permission to live here (if so how can I apply for it).
My GF is Italian so she wanted to know before we get married, so it would be great help for me if you have any solution for this.

Comment: Your nationality and how you arrived there at the first place is relevant!

Comment: @user8725 why would manner of arrival be relevant?  As to nationality, it only matters to the extent that OP is or isn't an EU/EEA/Swiss citizen, and the question is essentially trivial if he is.  We can therefore assume that he is not.

Comment: I do not know Italy's rules, but in Spain, some things are easy to get IF you are not in the country "irregularly."  "Situación irregular" is the exact words in the laws I have read.  I have seen no official definition of "irregular" in any of those laws, but they denied my NIE saying that I was in "irregular situation" in that I had allegedly overstayed on the 90/180 rule.  It wasn't true, and I got them to reverse it, but the point is that an overstay was reason for denial of something that the law required to be otherwise automatic.

Comment: Due to the efforts to make many things uniform throughout EU, I would suspect Italy's laws are similar.  The Spanish laws I read made several references to EU issues.

Comment: Are you actually saying that you are in the country illegaly and without a refugee status?